# GWT File download on optional location

Tags: java, excel, gwt, apache-poi

I have found this example on gwt: http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFileUpload

But instead of uploading a file I want to download a file to an optional location. I already have the apache poi working server side in my gwt location. But at the moment I have only made it save to a hardcoded destination on the C:\ drive. Instead I want to provide an optional save location in the gui.

I am thinking that I should just optain the file location as a string and send it to my server side exportToExcell class?!

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The download location is dictated by the browser choice (default or save as dialog) and cannot be overridden via javascript or GWT code.

The only way to achieve a custom download location would involve writing server side code in the servlet allowing access to write to "custom" folder with sufficient privileges. There are several limitations to it in terms of access being restricted to "webapps" folder.

Additional Read -> http://java.dzone.com/articles/file-system-storage-and